# Twitter Sharing in iOS 11

Tags: ios, twitter, ios11

I would like to ask for clarification about Twitter sharing in iOS 11 onwards.

The official Apple documentation states in the release notes the following:

> Social accounts have been removed from Settings in iOS 11. Third-party apps no longer have access to those signed-in accounts. (31687059)

And the official Twitter documentation [here](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/migrate-social-framework) states that:

> iOS 11 no longer supports using Twitter through the built-in social framework. Instead, you can use Twitter Kit 3 to Tweet, log in users, and use the Twitter API.

I'm having a bit of a hard time trying to understand how this changes affects sharing from apps.

Currently, using the "Social" Framework, one could simply use **SLComposeViewController** to easily share through several services.

With this change it seems **SLComposeViewController** can STILL be used as long as the user has the corresponding app installed, since THAT app will show it's own share sheet automatically. But if the app is not installed, it will just silently fail (based on my experiments).

*Currently the twitter one is showing a "No Twitter Account" alert message, but I believe this is a bug.

If the correct behavior is the one described above, then my understanding is correct. However, the twitter documentation makes it sound as if the Social framework will just not work for twitter anymore.

Additionally, "SLServiceTypeTwitter" is now shown as deprecated, meaning it's a bad idea to keep relying on it. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/social/slservicetypetwitter

Could someone clarify this for me?

PD: I'm sure this applies to other social services as well.

Comment: I want to share in twitter so what should I use in iOS 11?

Comment: you can use the SLComposeViewController for a fast implementation, but it will *probably not work anymore on iOS 12, so it might be best to use Twitter's SDK.

Comment: Do you know about Twitter SDK? If you know then please guide me.

Comment: Just follow their guide, its very easy to understand:
https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/installation

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its really easy to understand.

Comment: @Pochi Put if you don't have twitter app installed or user currently not log in, it just silently fails. Is there any way to detect this kind of thing? Before we can do `if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)` and this will return false if we don't have twitter app installed. but since iOS 11, it doesn't work anymore. In Twitter Doc, they say that we can do this `if (Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.hasLoggedInUsers())` but  
it seems that the docs are very outdated. Methods like `hasLoggedInUsers()` don't appear in the header file anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The people from twitter answered my question. It seems to be a bug right now:

https://twittercommunity.com/t/bug-in-ios-11/91490

However, it's still unconfirmed if this will be the default behavior for iOS 11.

---

**EDIT:**

The issue was fixed in version Twitter.app (7.7.2)

---

**EDIT 2:**

For clarification, this behavior should no longer occur if the user has the Twitter.app (version 7.72 and up) installed, since the sharing window is actually provided by the Twitter app. (Same as Facebook sharing)

Comment: I don't understand your answer. If SLServiceTypeTwitter is deprecated, what are we supposed to use?

Comment: @matt I think you are supposed to migrate into using their official SDK as SLServiceTypeTwitter will probably not work anymore on iOS 12. At least we still have around a year to do so. But regarding my answer, if you tried sharing using the native iOS sharing thing around the time i wrote my answer, you would get an error but still be able to share. This was a really odd behavior so I contacted the people at twitter and they told me it was a bug and now even though it's deprecated you can still share normally without any errors being shown.

Comment: Is it possible to share with twitter not installed

Comment: Yes but you have to use their official SDK directly.