# Twitter share in iOS 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, share

I am searching for twitter share image and video in iOS 13. I tried this one but "SLServiceTypeTwitter" is deprecated in iOS 11.

```
SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
[tweetSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter.png"]];
[tweetSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {

}];

[self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

Other way I find to share using API.
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload
Which needs user authorization.

Please suggest me which is the best way to share image and videos.

or is there any way to just open twitter app with image and video share if app is installed in the device.

Comment: I wrote a tutorial how to do this. Check it out: https://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com/2016/01/how-to-using-slrequest-to-upload-image.html

Comment: @GeneCode I am bit confused, SLServiceTypeTwitter and accounts in settings is deprecated in iOS 11, it will be available if I am targeting min version iOS 13?

Comment: Yes. Deprecated means they plan to remove it later but not yet. So you actually can use deprecated function up to a certain IOS version. Definitely no issues to use in iOS13

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Twitter Sharing in iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45450300/twitter-sharing-in-ios-11)